# How to fix Vitest proxy usage while testing?

Tags: reactjs, axios, proxy, vite, vitest

I'm using Vite with Vitest for testing, the api service itself uses Axios for http client.

The proxy config works well if I run the server in dev, but while testing it doesn't.
I can mock it to make it work, but I want to do some integration tests between frontend - working backend for real life scenarios.

This is the current Vite config (vitest config included):

```
  '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:8080',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,
          rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
        },
```

```
 test: {
      globals: true,
      environment: 'jsdom',
    },
```

Is there a way to make it work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I wonder the exact same thing. Did you find a solution for this?